# How can I pass the current post taxonomy term using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a filter for a wordpress custom post type.  I want to be able to dynamically display more posts using a dropdown.  This works fine.  The issue is that I'm only getting it to work if I hard code the taxonomy term.  I'd like to be able to pass the term dynamically with the number of posts per page that the use has selected.

I've already tried to pass it using a hidden input.  I was able to create the variable and add it to the name attribute but couldn't pull it out on the server side.  I also think that was a hacky way of doing it.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'posts_per_page' => $_POST['ppp'],
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'terminals'
                ),
            ),
        );
```

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <select name="ppp">
        <option value="1">Show 12 Per Page</option>
        <option value="2">Show 24 Per Page</option>
        <option value="3">Show 48 Per Page</option>
        <option value="-1">Show All</option>
    </select>
    <!-- <div id = "spinner"></div> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

```
$('#filter').change(function() {
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(),
            type:filter.attr('method'),
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                //show the spinner
            },
            success:function(data){
                //hide the spinner
                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I'd like to be able to grab the taxonomy term from the current post and pass it to the function through ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up digging into this a bit more based on Twisty's response and what I found I ended up adding the taxonomy term in as a hidden input value:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'posts_per_page' => $_POST['ppp'],
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $_POST['term']
                ),
            ),
        );
```

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="tax-filter">
                            <label>
                            <select name="ppp">
                                <option value="12">Show 12 Per Page</option>
                                <option value="24">Show 24 Per Page</option>
                                <option value="48">Show 48 Per Page</option>
                                <option value="-1">Show All</option>
                            </select>
                            <?php //get the post taxonomy term
                            $obj = get_queried_object(); ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="term" value="<?php echo $obj->slug; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
                        </form>
```

```
$('#tax-filter').change(function() {
    var filter = $('#tax-filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type:filter.attr('method'),
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            $('#spinner').toggle();
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#spinner').toggle();
            $('#sortedPosts').html(data);
        }
    });
    //debugging
    //console.log(filter.attr('method'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector is a bit off. Please consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#filter select").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().submit();
  });
  $("#filter").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $f = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: $f.attr("action"),
      data: {
        ppp: parseInt($("select", $f).val())
      },
      dataType: "html",
      method: "POST",
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        //show the spinner
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //hide the spinner
        $('#response').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
  <select name="ppp">
    <option value="1" selected>Show 12 Per Page</option>
    <option value="2">Show 24 Per Page</option>
    <option value="3">Show 48 Per Page</option>
    <option value="-1">Show All</option>
  </select>
  <!-- <div id = "spinner"></div> -->
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

When the User changes the `select`, the form is submitted. Form submission executes the AJAX.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry but that part is actually working fine (the posts per page).  I need to be able to pass a second data parameter using 'post'.  Right now the taxonomy term is hardcoded ```'terms'    => 'terminals'``` and I need to be able to use a variable there to replace "terminals" with whatever the term is for that actual post.  I know how to get the wordpress variable, I just don't know how to pass it as a second data attribute.

Comment: @MikeOberdick it would be passed in the same `data` that is sent for `ppp`, like `{ ppp: 1, tax: "terminals" }`